# Python Binary Tree property issue in class

Tags: python, list, tree, binary

I receive error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 36, in 
    root.data.append("L")
AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'data'

But i clearly have a data property in my class?

```
class Node:
    def _init_(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = list()

def addPerson(root, person):
    if person < root.data[0]:
        if root.left == None:
            root.left = Node()
            root.left.data.append(person)
        else:
            addPerson(root.left,person)
    else:
        if person > root.data[0]:
            if root.right == None:
                root.right = Node()
                root.right.data.append(person)
            else:
                addPerson(root.right,person)
        else:
            root.data.append(person)

def printPerson(root):
    if root == None:
        return
    print(root.data)
    printPerson(root.left)
    printPerson(root.right)

root = Node()
root.data.append("L")

for i in range(0,6):
    addPerson(root, input("Add Person: "))

print("Left side of room A-K: ")
printPerson(root.left)
print("Right side of room L-Z: ")
printPerson(root.right)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initialization method name is incorrect, it should be `__init__`. These magic methods are often referred to as "dunders" because they begin and end with double underscores. Change your `Node` class definition to this:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = list()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names

Comment: WOW! can't believe i didn't catch that....new to python. C++ and C# is my normal language but I am in a course in school that is using python. Thanks

Comment: @ZacharyDaniels, it's happened to the best of us. I use a font which renders a blank pixel between adjacent underscores in order to avoid mistaking one underscore for two.